# C getprotobyname adding protocols

Tags: c, protocols

I am working on an assignment for a school project. I am using getprotobyname to print out information about protocols like this:

```
int main(){
        char name[200], **p=NULL;
        struct protoent *prot; //definieer hier prot als pointer naar struct protoent
        scanf("%s", name);

        prot = getprotobyname(name);  // haal proto struct op
        if (prot == NULL){
                printf("error %s not found\n", name);
                return 1;
        }
        printf("official name: %s\n",prot->p_name);
        // druk ook het NUMMER af van het protocol
        printf( "proto number: %d\n", prot->p_proto);

        //en de aliassen:
        for (p = prot->p_aliases;*p != NULL; p++){
                printf("alias %s\n",*p);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

But to complete the assignment I also need to be able to print out a custom protocol, is there any way to add one? I can't seem to find it anywhere. Can anyone help me figure this out or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is just add protocol by editing the [/etc/protocols](http://linux.die.net/man/5/protocols) file which defines protocols.